# Castle Windsor re-create instance

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I am trying to dispose all of my business-logics services after each WCF call and trying to achieve it by using windsor (Ninject just didn't work), I have a following container class:

```
    public class LDSWindsorContainer : WindsorContainer
    {
        public LDSWindsorContainer()
        {
            AddFacility<WcfFacility>().
                Register(
                    Component.For<IDomainService>().ImplementedBy<DomainService>().LifeStyle.PerWcfOperation(),
                    Component.For<IChangeLogService>().ImplementedBy<ChangeLogService>().LifeStyle.PerWcfOperation(),
                    Component.For<ILogService>().ImplementedBy<LogService>().LifeStyle.PerWcfOperation(),
                    Component.For<ICentreInformationService>()
                        .ImplementedBy<CentreInformationService>()
                        .LifeStyle.PerWcfOperation().OnCreate(x=>Debug.WriteLine("Created")),
                    Component.For<ICentreService>().ImplementedBy<CentreService>().LifeStyle.PerWcfOperation(),
                    Component.For<ITimeZoneService>().ImplementedBy<TimeZoneService>().LifeStyle.PerWcfOperation(),
                    Component.For<IBrandService>().ImplementedBy<BrandService>().LifeStyle.PerWcfOperation(),
                    Component.For<IPricingService>().ImplementedBy<PricingService>().LifeStyle.PerWcfOperation(),
                    Component.For<IDirectoryService>()
                        .ImplementedBy<DirectoryService>().LifestyleSingleton());
        }
    }
```

all of the objects except the IDirectoryService and its' implementations are my business-logics services, the last one is a WCF service itself, I have the following Application_Start() method:

```
         public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
         {

             protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
             {
                 var container = new LDSWindsorContainer();
                 ...
             }
         }
```

and the constructor of my service look like:

```
            private ILogService Logger { get; set; }
            private IDomainService DomainService { get; set; }
            private ICentreInformationService CentreInformationService { get; set; }
            private ICentreService CentreService { get; set; }
            private ITimeZoneService TimeZoneService { get; set; }
            private IBrandService BrandService { get; set; }
            private IPricingService PricingService { get; set; }

            public DirectoryService(IBrandService brandService, ITimeZoneService timeZoneService, ICentreService centreService, ICentreInformationService centreInformationService, IDomainService domainService, ILogService logger, IPricingService pricingService)
            {
                BrandService = brandService;
                TimeZoneService = timeZoneService;
                CentreService = centreService;
                CentreInformationService = centreInformationService;
                DomainService = domainService;
                Logger = logger;
                PricingService = pricingService;
            }
```

I also have a corresponding line in my DirectoryService.svc and Web.config -

```
Factory="Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.DefaultServiceHostFactory, Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration
```

and

```
 <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
          <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" />
        </modules>
 </system.webServer>
```

So far the problem is: my instances are getting resolved once (for the first call), work fine, get disposed on call end and are not re-instantiated for all the upcoming calls, so basically I'm just getting an exception for working with a disposed object, any ideas are greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Your directory service is configured as a singleton, but the dependencies which are injected in are configured per request, so this would be normal behavior I think. You need to either make your directory service lifestyle per web request or make your other services singletons too.

Comment: Unfortunately in this particular case I can not change the behavior of the service but need to take advantage of per request DI, so I'm still looking for an option here

Comment: When you say you can't change the behavior, do you mean you can't change the lifestyle of the services? Also does directory service need to be a singleton?

Comment: Yes, my IDirectoryService should remain singleton and only singleton, long story short that's a behavior I'm not allowed to change, anything else - no problems

Comment: But you said you need to take advantage of per-request lifestyle? Why is that? Do each caller need their own instances of these dependencies?

Comment: In general - my services (other than IDirectoryService) are my business logics services and contain a db context instance in them, I need to dispose it after each request in order to avoid caching as data in the DB is manipulated by multiple independent applications.

Comment: If you have a Singleton with dependencies that are PerWcfOperation, you're going to have a bad time. It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after some struggle I was able to find a perfect answer here -

My container settings:

```
     AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>().Register(Component.For<IDomainService>().ImplementedBy<DomainService().LifeStyle.PerWcfOperation(),

     AddFacility<WcfFacility>().Register(Component.For<IDirectoryService>().ImplementedBy<DirectoryService>().LifestyleSingleton());
```

Where IDomainService is my business logics service that I want to dispose after each request and IDirectoryService is my WCF service.

My service sontructor

```
    public DirectoryService(Func<IDomainService> domainService)
    {
        DomainServiceFactory = domainService;
    }
```

and some sugar to avoid all calls renaming:

```
    private Func<IDomainService> DomainServiceFactory { get; set; }

    private IDomainService DomainService
    {
        get { return DomainServiceFactory(); }
    }
```

Comment: Presumably you have one of these for every dependency? An interesting solution, but it seems you're embedding knowledge/assumptions about the lifecycle of IDomainService into DirectoryService. IoC/DI is generally about decoupling dependencies, whereas this solution, while allowing for type substitution, leaves things very tightly coupled. For example, if the lifecycle of one of your dependencies is altered from PerWcfOperation to Transient then your service would likely fail.

Comment: Well all that stuff will not get changed to transient because it is intended to dispose services after every request so my db context querries will not get cached.

Comment: You're dealing with what Mark Seemann refers to as the Captive Dependency problem: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/ Yes your solution will work but is extremely brittle and makes me wonder what value you're adding with DI. It seems that what is going on here is very confusing for someone maintaining this code later.